# How can I make a dropdown inside on iframe drop down on top of the other frames

Tags: html, css

I have the following in my frameset.jsp

```
</head>

       <iframe width="100%" src="mail_frame.html"></iframe>

       <iframe width="105px" height="100%" src="sidenav.html" id="leftnav" name="leftnav" ></iframe>

       <iframe height="100%" src="body.htm" id="main" name="main"></iframe>


</html>
```

How can I make a drop down contained in mail_frame.html drop down and and overlap the other two frames below it?

Comment: Change your iframes to divs with `overflow:scroll` and it should work instantly...

Comment: If your pages are dynamic (as the `.jsp` ending suggests), why don't you (server-side) put the iframe pages' content where your iframes are instead?

Comment: @martin the div idea seems to be working. the only problem is that i cant set the height. ive tried height="105px" it dindt work.i also tried style="height:105px" but it doesnt seem to be affecting the div at all. any ideas?
.
.
<div width="100%" style="position: absolute; height: 105px;" id="mail" name="mail" ><jsp:include page="mail_frame.html" /></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Frame content is contained within the frame and cannot be positioned outside of it.

It could be faked with cross-frame Javascript that triggers displaying the dropdown in another frame, but that is a hack and will result in headaches.

You are probably better off by not using frames, which is easy if you use some kind of server-side script that includes mail_frame.html, sidenav.html and body.html in one page.

It would look something like this in PHP: (you'll have to adjust it a bit for yourself to make it work)

```
</head>

       <div id="mail_frame"><?php include('mail_frame.html'); ?></div>

       <div id="leftnav"><?php include('sidenav.html'); ?></div>

       <div id="main"><?php include('body.html'); ?></div>

</html>
```